# simplifying with exponents that must be positive

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

$$\frac{\sqrt{c\cdot \:a^2}\cdot \:b^2}{c^2\cdot \left(a^{-1}\cdot \:b^3\right)^{-3}}$$

Now this should simplify to

$$\frac{b^{11}\sqrt{c}}{c^2a^2}$$

My question is why is it important that $a, b$ and c$ variables are positive ?

Comment: is it because we have to assume that $a ≥ 0$ when we $\sqrt[n]{a^n}=a,$

Comment: In particular when $n$ is even, $\sqrt[n]{a^n} = |a|$.

Comment: yeah but it should still be that if I want to factor $a^2$ it needs to be positive no ?

Comment: from inside the square root, yes.

Comment: yeah a negative numbers needs to be inside parentheses like this to work $√(-2)^2$

Comment: It still dosen't. $\sqrt {(-2)^2} = 2 \ne -2$

Comment: yeah nvm that doesnt work for my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the numbers were negative, then $\sqrt{c\cdot a^2}$ would have a negative number inside the radical. Obviously this can't be true for real numbers, so all numbers must be positive.

In general, when $n$ is even, $\sqrt[n]{a^n} = |a|.$